# Legend for additional points in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Steeling the example of this question ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000944/adding-a-point-to-the-ggplot-messes-up-the-legend)), I want to ask if it is possible to add the additional blue point to the legend?

```
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
              xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3),
              yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))
g1 <- dat[15,]

ggplot(dat, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, shape = cond, 
                     colour = cond), size = 2.5) + 
geom_point(alpha = 1) +
geom_point(data = g1, colour = "blue", size = 4, show_guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put the aesthetics for the additional points layer inside `aes` instead of outside to get it added to the legend.  You can use any string value; that string will be the name in the legend.

Then you can control the color and shape of that point via `scale_*_manual` layers.

I additionally changed the size of that point in the legend using `override.aes`, which is optional.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, shape = cond, 
                colour = cond), size = 2.5) + 
     geom_point(alpha = 1) +
     geom_point(data = g1, aes(colour = "Point 15", shape = "Point 15"), size = 4) +
     scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17, 17) ) +
     scale_color_manual(values = c("pink", "turquoise", "blue") ) +
     guides(color = guide_legend( override.aes = list(size = c(1.5, 1.5, 4) ) ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to change the condition of that point in the data as in your example or add it to the date, if it is not already part of it.

```
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
          xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3),
          yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))
dat$size = 2.5
dat[15,]$cond = "C"
dat$cond = as.character(dat$cond)
dat[15,]$size = 4

ggplot(dat, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, shape = cond, 
                 colour = cond, size=size)) + 
geom_point(alpha = 1) +
scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "turquoise", "blue")) +
scale_size_continuous(guide = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Benjamin :) It works fine! You just need to correct the typo "manuel" to "manual" and define the column cond as a character